# How to change the width of the middle line in box whisker plot in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the current version of `ggplot2`, the middle line in a box-whisker-plot is drawn bold compared to the other lines:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

I think this was not the case in some older versions. Is there a way to separately adjust the width of the middle line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Poorly documented](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/664), but you can use the `fatten` argument in `geom_boxplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(fatten = 0)
```

[image]

```
p + geom_boxplot(fatten = 4)
```

[image]